# Transitioning from Phonegap to a native app

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

We are looking to create an app for the educational industry. First app and we thought we could maybe start with Phonegap to speed things up, then transition to an Objective-C iPad app in the future.

Does anyone know what that transition would look like? We are hoping that it could be a v1.x to v2.0 update on the same app on iOS without having to install a new app. We are not concerned about Android users (sorry), the edu field is all Apple at the moment.

Thanks in advance

BITs

Answer (score 3):

The transition would be as follows:

1. You shall learn Objective-C and the Cocoa Touch API in order to make a native iOS app.
2. You will then need to rewrite all of the HTML/CSS/JavSscript source code, to produce an equivalent application, in Objective-C.
   (2.5 it might be tricky if your app talks to a webservice using AJAX etc. -- native networking is not at all as trivial as from the web browser from JS.)
3. An update in the AppStore shall be perfectly fine afterwards -- PhoneGap just uses a native 'skeleton' app to embed a web browser view, so no significant change will be required.

Comment: +1 not gonna be easy, like writing a new app (because it's a complete rewrite)